# PowerShell Remote Installation of exe - Not able to install

Tags: powershell

I am trying to install exe on remote machine by using below script, but it didn't succeed. The exe file is on remote machine.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName COMPUTER -ScriptBlock{
    Start-Process c:\Windows\Temp\ccsetup.exe -ArgumentList '/silent' -Wait
}
```

I tried giving different paths but it is not helpful.

Comment: Does the file exist in that path on the remote machine? Are you getting an error? What does it say?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers He says in his question that it does.

Comment: Try using `Invoke-Command -CN $CN { Test-Path 'c:\Windows\Temp\ccsetup.exe' }` and see what it returns

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, Yes the exe is on remote machine. I didn't see any error. It is waiting waiting for 'n' amount of time.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1, i tried the command test-path, and it returned "True"

Comment: @BhanuprakashMankala Maybe the exe is running but waiting for additional input. Are you sure it just requires the `silent` parameter?

Comment: @Jelphy,,  I'm installing cclener software(exe), and i require silent installation. For that, i have used "silent"

Comment: @BhanuprakashMankala Try using the `-RedirectStandardOutput/-RedirectStandardError` parameters on `Start-Process` to see what console output is happening.  They require a file location like `C:\Temp\out.txt`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1, i tried and nothing was write into the output file /error file

Comment: @BhanuprakashMankala This [link](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/faq/installing/can-ccleaner-be-installed-and-run-silently) states you are missing `/AUTO` switch?

Comment: @BhanuprakashMankala The files would be locally on the remote computer.

Comment: Good lord. Installing CCleaner? The script is doing you a favor by bombing.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1, Yes, i have searched the files on remote computer. It didn't write anything.

Comment: @Jelphy, I am trying the script like below. 
Start-Process PATH -ArgumentList /AUTO. Is it correct way?

Comment: @BhanuprakashMankala `'/AUTO, /S'` I think.

Comment: @Jelphy incorrect.  `'/auto','/s'`

Comment: I have tried with the arguments but no luck. My doubt the arguments are application specific? Currently i'm trying for CCleaner but i need remote installation for 4-5 software, then do i need to check arguments for individual exe's? Why can't we write a generic script so that it will be reused for all the exe?

Comment: @Jelphy, If I run same command on remote machine directly(local execution) it was working. But, the same not happening on remote execution.

Comment: Am I missing something? Pls. help

Comment: Setup log has any events during this time?Could you try  ` -ArgumentList "/S","/AUTO" `

Comment: @BhanuprakashMankala How are you passing the `-ArgumentList` ? Something like this: `-ArgumentList "'/AUTO', '/S'"`